# iterate all data in firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making an android app to average all rating data in Firestore. This is the structure of my Firestore. I want to retrieve all rating_num which are [1, 4, 5] using DocumentSnapshot

```
reviews
|-my_document1
  |- rating_num:1
|-my_document2
  |- rating_num:4
|-my_document3
  |- rating_num:5
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("reviews").whereEqualTo(rating_num,??) //no clue
        query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
              @Override
              public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                  Log.d("debug", "print all rating number using for loop");
                  for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                      String cum_rating = document.getString("avg_quality");
                      Log.d("debug", cum_rating);
                  }
              }
          });
```

I have no clue how to match the only rating_num in all of my documents, and it does not show anything in my for loop, any help would appreciate.

Please also note that there is no need to call any `.whereEqualTo()`, as you don't need to match any property to a specific value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value of `rating_num` property from all documents and create an average, please use the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference reviewsRef = rootRef.collection("reviews");
reviewsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            long count = 0;
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                count =+ document.getLong("rating_num");
            }
            long average = count / task.getResult().getDocuments().size();
            Log.d("TAG", "avarage: " + average);
        }
    }
});
```

If you only have three documents with those three values, 1, 4, and 5, the result in the logcat will be:

```
3.33
```